# Drink in the passive voice

Tags: past-participles

Is the following sentence correct?

> The milk was drunk by him.

I don't think I've heard anyone use the past participle of drink in the passive voice.

Comment: But you must have heard the adjective participle: "He was drunk"

Comment: Funny. Sounds like I have heard it a plenty of times. And that is generally the common construct: proper form of 'to be' + past participle. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: For some reason I'm inclined to use "drunken" in this case. Is this totally wrong? Are there other past participles that have an -en ending?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's quite correct.

Your particular example is not very likely, since "He drank the milk" is simpler and shorter.

It is easy to find examples on the internet:

> Milk is drunk all over the world, in all cultures.

> Most milk is drunk fresh.